# Is it possible to add an edit page button to edit AND save the webpage?

Tags: html, text, editor

I currently have a basic one page website and want to add in an edit page button. I have this button link to and empty html doc that is protected with and encrypted password. Would it be possible to add a text editor in this second html doc to edit the first html document along with saving the edits?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you include images and/or code in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure html this isn't possible.

The common way would be to store your first page in a database, get the data via php. Then the second site could be a edit page for the data in the database.

Have a look at this tutorial: https://www.elated.com/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/